# Git command to determine if a directory will be present in a clone after running commit?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

Im writing a git pre commit hook (for use on windows and osx), and I need to know if a directory will be present if I clone the repo after committing the currently staged mods. As directories are not tracked I need to know if there is a file that will be tracked in the directory or any of its subdirectories after committing. I currently use the following code, but it feels very shaky:

```csharp
public bool TrackedAfterCommit(IDirectory directory)
{
    var dirs = new Stack<IDirectory>();
    dirs.Push(directory);

    while (dirs.Count > 0)
    {
        var d = dirs.Pop();

        foreach (var f in d.Files)
        {
            var command = new ConsoleCommand(
                "git",
                "status --porcelain --ignored " + f.Path, directory.Path
            );
            var output = command.Execute();

            if (output.Count == 0)
                return true;

            var status = output[0];

            if (!status.StartsWith("D")
                && !status.StartsWith("??")
                && !status.StartsWith("!"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        foreach (var dir in d.Directories)
            dirs.Push(dir);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all directories containing git-controlled files on a branch `BRANCH` using this:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree BRANCH | xargs -n 1 dirname | sort -u
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it has to work on windows (and osx), preferably without additional dependencies

Comment: If you have Git for Windows, this will work just fine from Git Bash. Similar for Mac OS X (unless their BSD tools again differ in command line options from the GNU ones).